# JQuery accordion: applying unique style to "open" state

Tags: jquery, accordion

I found a simple JQuery accordion structure that uses DIV's rather than the typical UL structure.

When you click on the *menu* DIVS, a specific corresponding *panel* DIV slides open.
How do I make it so that when a panel is open, it's corresponding *menu* DIV gets a diffent style applied to it?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu1").data("panelId", "#collapse_about");
    $("#menu2").data("panelId", "#collapse_portfolio");
    $("#menu3").data("panelId", "#collapse_contact");

    $("#menu1, #menu2, #menu3").click(function() {
        var first = true;
        var panelId = $(this).data("panelId");
        $(".class1").not(panelId).slideUp(function() {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
                $(panelId).slideToggle(400);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.class1 {width:200px; height:200px; border:1px solid black; display:none;}
 #collapse_about {background:red; margin-bottom:10px;}
 #collapse_portfolio {background:blue; margin-bottom:10px;}
 #collapse_contact {background:orange; margin-bottom:10px;}
  #menu1 {cursor:pointer; display:block; width:200px; border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:10px;}
 #menu2 {cursor:pointer; display:block; width:200px; border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:10px;}
 #menu3 {cursor:pointer; display:block; width:200px; border:1px solid black; margin-bottom:10px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="menu1">Menu 1</div>
<div id="collapse_about" class="class1">Content 1</div>
<div id="menu2">Menu 2</div>
<div id="collapse_portfolio" class="class1">Content 2</div>
<div id="menu3">Menu 3</div>
<div id="collapse_contact" class="class1">Content 3</div>
```

Here is the code on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/aTR2b/2/

I would really appreciate any help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is ur answer:

http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/aTR2b/3/

i added to the css:

```
.menu_active{ background: grey;}
```

And to the js:

```
$("#menu1, #menu2, #menu3").click(function() {
    $(".menu_active").removeClass('menu_active');
    $(this).addClass('menu_active');
    //... rest of the fn
```

Comment: and then what is proper manner on stackoverflow when u get the correct answer u want. u select it as 'accepted' than people will most likely help u more on future Q's :-)

Comment: Oh, I thought I did that already. Is that the big green tick?

Comment: :) Thanks. As you prob guessed, I'm new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Neal, is there a way to make the _menu_ div return to it's original state (i.e. not grey) when you _re_ -collapse a panel?

Comment: lol u can check if it is grey, and if it is, than remove the class

Comment: I've tried updating the JS to check if it has the "grey" class, and if it does, to remove this and add the old class, but I don't know how to make it revert back to the same class that it had before. My JS knowledge is terrible. If you have time to look at it, here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/aTR2b/5/ If not, don't worry.

Answer (score -1):

The Menu div will get the style ui-state-active applied to it when it's open.  Use that.